# jQuery animation opacity doesn't work in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, opacity

I have a strange problem on the intro of [my site](http://www.svlhandbags.com/) with jQuery animation. I load content with views/drupal, en set display to none. Then I want to fade in and out each row.

All works great in all browsers, but not in IE... Anybody has an idea why?

```
jQuery('.view-intro').find('.views-row-1')
    .css('display','block')
    .animate({opacity: 1.00}, time_short, 'swing')
    .animate({opacity: 1.00}, time_long, 'linear')
    .animate({opacity: 0.00}, time_short, 'swing', function(){

        jQuery('.view-intro').find('.views-row-1').css('display','none')

        jQuery('.view-intro').find('.views-row-2')
        .css('display','block')
        .animate({opacity: 1.00}, time_short, 'swing')
        .animate({opacity: 1.00}, time_long, 'linear')
        .animate({opacity: 0.00}, time_short, 'swing', function(){

            jQuery('.view-intro').find('.views-row-2').css('display','none')

            jQuery('.view-intro').find('.views-row-3')
            .css('display','block')
            .animate({opacity: 1.00}, time_short, 'swing')
            .animate({opacity: 1.00}, time_long, 'linear')
            .animate({opacity: 0.00}, time_short, 'swing', function(){

                jQuery('.view-intro').find('.views-row-3').css('display','none')

                jQuery('.view-intro').css('display', 'none')
                jQuery('.view-collections').animate({opacity: 1, paddingLeft: 0}, time_short, 'swing')

            })
        })
    })
```

Comment: Have you tried using `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` instead? jQuery should take care of cross browser issues here. Also you can just use `.show()` and `.hide()` (or even `.toggle()`) instead of using `.css('display',`

Answer (score 0):

IE8 and below do not recognise the opacity css property, so I recommend you use fadeTo(), that should work.